# 'eternal' (ohne Anfang und Ende) und 'everlasting' (ohne Ende) im Deutschen

Tags: difference, word-usage

In [dieser Antwort auf christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1860/who-created-god/1869#1869) steht folgender Satz:

> Don't confuse *eternal* (having no beginning or end) with *everlasting* (just having no end).

<sub>(Hervorhebung von mir.)</sub>

Kennt das Deutsche diese Unterscheidung? Mit welchen Wörtern kann man das Eine und das Andere am besten ausdrücken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**eternal**: immer oder immer während

```
Ein mathematisches Theorem gilt immer.
```

**everlasting**: ewig, fortwährend

```
Das schreckliche Ereignis wird uns ewig in Erinnerung bleiben.

Der King of Pop wird uns ewig in Erinnerung bleiben.
```

Auf jeden Fall wird **ewig** sehr häufig in Zusammenhängen gebraucht, die einen Anfang haben. Ewiges Leben (Geburt).

Außerdem fehlt der dritte Begriff, der sich nur auf die Vergangenheit bezieht: seit Ewigkeiten, schon immer.

Es ist im Deutschen jedenfalls schwierig Begriffe zu finden, die bezüglich der Vergangenheit unbegrenzt sind.

Theologisch setzt die Schöpfungsgeschichte einen Anfang.

Brauchen tut man die Unterscheidung ja eigentlich auch nur, um verschiedene kosmologische Modelle zu unterscheiden und das ist im praktischen Alltagsleben ziemlich unwichtig. Ich vermute fast wird haben im deutschen hier keine klaren Begriffe und die Bedeutung erschließt sich erst im Kontext.

Comment: Das Beispiel für "ethernal" war _Gott_ (hat keinen Anfang, da sonst die Frage ist, wer ihn geschaffen hat).

Comment: Der Einwand ist Unfug, denn die Aussage, es habe Gott schon immer gegeben ist ja nur eine Ausrede, nicht zeigen zu müssen, wo er herkommt. Oder umgekehrt: Wer einräumt, dass es sein kann, dass etwas immer schon existiert hat, könnte das ja auch für Materie und Energie behaupten, und würde damit die Notwendigkeit Gott zu erfinden, aus der Welt schaffen. Die Frage, wer Gott geschaffen hat, ist aber gelöst: der Mensch war's.

Comment: Die Schaffung und Erhaltung der Götter ist sehr schön Terry Pratchetts “Einfach göttlich“ (Small gods) nachzulesen.

Answer (score 1):

"Unendlich" oder "ewig" für "eternal", "endlos" für "everlasting".